# Conditional rendring and wrapping two or more elements with the same type in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So here are my data structure:

```
components: [
 {code: "CMSParagraph_1610632439131", type: "CMSParagraph", version: "Staged",…}
 {code: "CMSImageZoom_1610618563282", type: "CMSImageZoom", version: "Staged",…}
 {code: "CMSImageZoom_1610556075701", type: "CMSImageZoom", version: "Staged",…}
 {code: "CMSParagraph_1610632439131", type: "CMSTitle", version: "Staged",…}
]
```

I want to render elements with the same type grouped by a div

something like :

```
<div>cmsParagraph</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>cmsImageZoom</div>
  <div>cmsImageZoom</div>
</div>
<div>cmsParagraph</div>
```

How can i achieve this, Any ideas !?

Answer (score 0):

I hope i've understood what you were talking about correctly.  Something like this might work:

```
let types = {};
for (let ele of components) {
  if (types[ele.type] === undefined) {
    types[ele.type] = [];
    types[ele.type].push({ ...ele });
  } else {
    types[ele.type].push({ ...ele });
  }
}

return ({
    Object.keys(types)
      .map((i) => {
        return types[i];
      })
      .map((arrOfTypei) => {
        <div>
           {  arrOfTypei.map((ele) => {
              return <Comp data={ele}/>
           })  }
        </div>
      })
});
```

We can just store the separate types in separate arrays, and then render each of those arrays into separate divs.

Comment: The problem here is, each of the elements will get wrapped up by a div i want only some element with a specific type to gets wrap inside a div. the others remains unctouched

Answer (score 0):

The desired behaviour is inside a map function if two element with the same type layes after each others i want to wrap them inside a div, and only if their type is eqaul to a specific type, if not i'm going to return.

Here's how i achieve it:

```
let arr = [];
const compoData = data && data.compo ? data.compo.containers : []
compoData.map((compo, index) => {

 let content = [];
 const {type} = compData;
 const cmp = <cmp {...props}>
 
 if(type === 'x') {
  arr.push(cmp)
 }else{

  if(arr && arr.length) {
     content.push(
      <TypeWrapper>{arr}</TypeWrapper>
     )
     arr = []
  }
  content.push(cmp)

 }

 if(!compoData[index +1]) {
    content.push((
      <TypeWrapper>{arr}</TypeWrapper>
    ))
 }

 return content && content

}
```